# Python Account for Nulls in Fixed Width Text File When Splitting

Tags: python, list, dataframe, split

Experts -

New to Python.  Need to know how to account for null values when splitting a fixed width text file (that gets loaded into a list)?  If a value is not null on one line and null on another the split function will return a different number of columns for different rows.  This messes things up downstream when trying to get the data into a Dataframe.

Thanks for the insight!

Answer (score 0):

This approach seems to work:

```
a = '123456789111                                 12346          123456        M0012345602     11/12/13  123.4   12     123 A1234'

b = a[16:30]
if b.isspace():
    a = a[0:12] + '   x    ' + a[30:120]
    print a
```